# How to get currentTabName from QTabWidget on Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qtabwidget

`QTabWidget` has a property called `currentTabName`.

[image]

How can I access the `currentTabName` by code?

I need to check what tab is selected, but I can't use the tab text (`tabText`) because it is translatable and may change and I don't want to use the tab index (`currentIndex`) because the index may change in the future.

I'm using Qt 5.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Chris Kawa answered [here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/80867/how-to-get-currenttabname-from-qtabwidget-on-qt/5) this is the object name of the current widget.

From code I can get it like this:

```
QString currentTabName = tabWidget->currentWidget()->objectName();
```

**Note**: As the doc suggest make sure to check for `nullptr` when using `tabWidget->currentWidget()`.

Comment: Yeah, I just found this out when I found out they were using designer. The relevant source code is here.
https://github.com/qt/qttools/blob/13946e382e7ab9418b4fe69a0b87a65d74c31bf4/src/designer/src/lib/shared/qdesigner_tabwidget.cpp#L443

Comment: Thanks Alexander. I have found the solution on the Qt forum. I didn't know that the `currentTabName` was the `objectName` from the `currentWidget`.